# Prefix notation in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I am working with Antlr4 at the moment, and I have a confusion with one example. I have to calculate value of expressions in prefix notation which implies following notation:

- ADD expr expr OR
- SUB expr expr OR
- MUL expr expr OR
- DIV expr expr OR
- Integer OR
- Double

(also every expression needs to have ';' at the end of it).

I have written grammar and regular expression for this, but I have a test example of a professor which says `ADD 1 2 SUB 1;`, which shouldn't even belong to this grammar right? Because for SUB operation I don't have two expressions from the right side? Would be grateful if someone could confirm this for me.

PS. I didn't post the code because for other examples it works, just this one reports error `"mismatched input on SUB ';'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expr rule is

```
expr : 'ADD' expr expr
     | 'SUB' expr expr
     | 'MUL' expr expr
     | 'DIV' expr expr
     | Integer
     | Double
     ;
```

then yes, `ADD 1 2 SUB 1` would not match it.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you for confirmation!